# Magento2 error: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error in magento 2 local system:

> We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.

It is not showing me the sample data installed in catalog. Please help me out to get solution of this problem.

Regards,

Rakesh Kumar

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is go to your .htaccess file. Uncomment

`SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer`

The error message is 90% of the time misleading and most likely you have an xml parsing issue. Either way turning on the developer environment and clearing the cache will pull the error.

Without seeing your error log it'd be hard to give an exact diagnosis. Some users will say sendmail will fix this error but generally this is because the error is trying to be emailed to you and that is because you are not in the correct developing environment to debug the issue. This could be because you are in default or production mode which is not ideal for fixing issue.

The sendmail module is meant to allow a site to operate and if any issues do occur with the site then the developer can be notified and hopefully the error hasn't caused a full site rendering issue. This way a site can still operate unbeknown to users and the issue can be resolved by a qualified developer behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

This error is quite misleading. In my case an error in MySql query was causing this.
You should enable developer mode the get the exact error.

```
php ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case issue get solved by giving permissions to directory `pub/media/catalog/product/`

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable developer mode using command line `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
2. Clear cache using command line `php bin/magento cache:flush`
3. Reload the frontend page
4. After reloading the page the message will change to

> Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory  \C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/m/b. Access forbidden.

5. Follow this link to fix [Magento 2: Unable to write file into directory. Access forbidden](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/170376)
6. Clear cache
7. Reload the frontend page again
8. If you see another message after enabling developer mode you can search for it

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing `php-gd` extension on my machine.

This was on my exception log (`magento_root/var/log/exception.log`):

> main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Required PHP extension 'gd' was not loaded.' in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:620

Solved by installing `php-gd` library on my Ubuntu machine with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install php-gd`

If you want to install for php5.6 then you may run:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd`

Answer (score 0):

This can be for any error occurred in the page. The notice is different. The notice is given when system tries to send error email to administrator and failed while in Production mode.

For actual error one should enable developer mode and enable display error in `app/bootstrap.php` and checking error logs. It can be any error like php or mysql.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your  /var/log/exception.log 
This is issue raised because your product does not upload. so check your database or upload your sample database again .Let me know  what error in  exception.log